# Slot Machine with List View

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, scroll

I want to use code for scrolling List View. But I don't know how scroll work in ListView, how get position. I use ScrollTo for change position, but position don't changed

Plan: Every tick move position of scroll use method ScrollTo. If border, then set position on opposition border.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System;
using Android.Media;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Views;

namespace TestChart
{
    [Activity(Label = "Slot Machine", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2","Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2" };


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Button buttonRoll = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonRoll);
            ListView listViewSlotMachine = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listViewSlotMachine);

            var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Resource.Layout.my_list_item, values);

            listViewSlotMachine.Adapter = adapter;

            buttonRoll.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                listViewSlotMachine.ScrollTo(0, 0); // don't changed
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for easier implementation, please use RecyclerView with recyclerView.smoothScrollTo(position)

Comment: Just imagine his "If border, then set position on opposition border." with your "smoothScrollTo"..

Comment: I found an android library which may help you implement slotmachine https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-wheel/

Comment: Can I do this without animation?